# ORDERY clause not working in simple db amazon in iphone application

Tags: ios, sql, amazon-web-services, sql-order-by, amazon-simpledb

I am using `ORDER BY` clause to fetch data but it does not work in simple db amazon web service data base.if i do not use the order by clause in query then it works fine other wise it crashed the app.

below is the code.

```
select = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * FROM ContentMaster  where ContentAddedByUserID='%@' AND HiveletCode='%@' ORDER BY ContentAddedDateTime DESC",appDelegate.userID,appDelegate.organizationCode];

SimpleDBGetAttributesRequest *gar = [[SimpleDBGetAttributesRequest alloc] initWithDomainName:DOMAIN_NAME andItemName:itemNameUser];
SimpleDBGetAttributesResponse *response = [sdbClient getAttributes:gar];

NSString*nextToken;

NSLog(@" Catgeory ID is %@ ", appDelegate.categoryID);

NSLog(@"%@ ", appDelegate.organizationCode);
SimpleDBSelectRequest *selectRequest = [[[SimpleDBSelectRequest alloc] initWithSelectExpression:select] autorelease];

NSLog(@"Select Request is %@",selectRequest);

selectRequest.consistentRead = YES;
nextToken = selectRequest.nextToken;
NSLog(@"Next Token is %@",nextToken);

SimpleDBSelectResponse *selectResponse = [sdbClient select:selectRequest];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SimpleDB documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/SortingDataSelect.html)

> The sort attribute must be present in at least one of the predicates of the expression.

This means you will probably need to change your query to:

```
select * FROM ContentMaster  where ContentAddedByUserID='%@' AND HiveletCode='%@' AND ContentAddedDateTime > 0 ORDER BY ContentAddedDateTime DESC
```

As for the crash, this an exception from the SDK, you should either disable exceptions and handle errors or put your calls in a @try/@catch block.  You can read more about how exceptions and errors are handled in the AWS SDK for iOS in [our blog](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2PZV371MJJHUG/How-Not-to-Throw-Exceptions-with-the-AWS-SDK-for-iOS).